# Adding line breaks after a specific pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file containing thousands of protein sequences, formatted like;

```
>EgrG_000615900transcript=EgrG_000615900gene=EgrG_000615900MAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV
```

Each protein is currently on its own line. The 'MAIRS...FFIV' represents the protein sequence and the stuff before it is the accession. i would like the protein to be on a new line, i.e. I want there to be a line break between '....EgrG_000615900' (the numbers here vary, but there are always 9 digits) and 'MAIRS....'. Ideally, the output would look like this;

```
>EgrG_000615900transcript=EgrG_000615900gene=EgrG_000615900
MAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV
```

Each protein in the file begins with the pattern `>EgrG_.........transcript=EgrG_.........gene=EgrG_.........` (dot representing any digit 0-9).

I have tried

```
sed  's/>EgrG_.........transcript=EgrG_.........gene=EgrG_........./&\n/g' input file > output file
```

but this doesn't work

UPDATE
Thank you everyone for your attention. In hindsight, I feel that I can simplify my request. Below is a larger sample from my file;

```
>EgrG_000615900 transcript=EgrG_000615900 gene=EgrG_000615900MAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV
>EgrG_001057700 transcript=EgrG_001057700 gene=EgrG_001057700MEESNSEPVIFQVSKLAGRHNYTSFGHKEDLDPQNKFSIPSPADHPGKHRSVLRSLFKGMSSGGKNVALEEQQPTYRQAGSSSHHRYHIHHYPHNPSDDRRPLRGPCFPHMSSSSQSASAFSSPNSSSSPGQRVSTFHAGLREEVLEQDGTSSTTQANFSEEPLVLLVLFPASKSKEAVLPLTTVGRNDCCATASVFTLRLASTYCDVAFFINYFS
>EgrG_000972800 transcript=EgrG_000972800 gene=EgrG_000972800MTSYCAVFMVPLLTLLILWGHLPACESTPLPSELIVRRGRTLQDLYRYVQQQYLMCLKCPNCPCETKFNIRRRSGGINWPQYMNASGMTAKNMEEALDDY
>EgrG_000198800 transcript=EgrG_000198800 gene=EgrG_000198800MPETGKSGGTTISSKTKSTAVSSGTPVKPMKSESCRLISGESPTSVVILKPAWASFVTPFPPVQEKCCKCGQLVRFSDRIELLGKVFHESCFRCAVCNRPLSNSEAIFHSNAWNCEAHASSYPRLYAS`
```

*Although it doesn't appear to be here, within my file, each of these four sequences are on a single line.* Although the digits of the accession change across the individual proteins, the number of characters remain the same (the accession can therefore be represented; `>EgrG_......... transcript=EgrG_......... gene=EgrG_.........`). You may notice that the actual protein sequence in each case begins with an 'M'. These are the only consistencies across all of the proteins/lines within my file. Currently, my file consists of the accession and protein sequence on a single line, but I would like the above sequences to be formatted;

```
>EgrG_000615900 transcript=EgrG_000615900 gene=EgrG_000615900
MAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV`
>EgrG_001057700 transcript=EgrG_001057700 gene=EgrG_001057700
MEESNSEPVIFQVSKLAGRHNYTSFGHKEDLDPQNKFSIPSPADHPGKHRSVLRSLFKGMSSGGKNVALEEQQPTYRQAGSSSHHRYHIHHYPHNPSDDRRPLRGPCFPHMSSSSQSASAFSSPNSSSSPGQRVSTFHAGLREEVLEQDGTSSTTQANFSEEPLVLLVLFPASKSKEAVLPLTTVGRNDCCATASVFTLRLASTYCDVAFFINYFS`
>EgrG_000972800 transcript=EgrG_000972800 gene=EgrG_000972800
MTSYCAVFMVPLLTLLILWGHLPACESTPLPSELIVRRGRTLQDLYRYVQQQYLMCLKCPNCPCETKFNIRRRSGGINWPQYMNASGMTAKNMEEALDDY
>EgrG_000198800 transcript=EgrG_000198800 gene=EgrG_000198800
MPETGKSGGTTISSKTKSTAVSSGTPVKPMKSESCRLISGESPTSVVILKPAWASFVTPFPPVQEKCCKCGQLVRFSDRIELLGKVFHESCFRCAVCNRPLSNSEAIFHSNAWNCEAHASSYPRLYAS`
```

i.e. accession on one line, protein sequence on the next. In summary, a line split between the

```
>EgrG_......... transcript=EgrG_......... gene=EgrG_.........
```

and the first 'M' is what is required.

Thank you again all for your patience

Comment: has the file other lines of other type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the twenty Amino Acids list, for extract protein sequence (IUPAC notation, without stop codon symbol)

```
alanine - A
arginine - R
asparagine - N
aspartic acid - D
cysteine - C
glutamine - Q
glutamic acid - E
glycine - G
histidine - H
isoleucine - I
leucine - L
lysine - K
methionine - M
phenylalanine - F
proline - P
serine - S
threonine - T
tryptophan - W
tyrosine - Y
valine - V

special cases:

asparagine/aspartic acid - B
glutamine/glutamic acid - Z
```

With `gnu-sed`:

```
sed -r 's/[ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYVBZ]+$/\n&/' file
```

With `sed`

```
sed 's/[ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYVBZ]*$/\'$'\n&/g' file
```

you get, `fasta` format corresponding,

```
>EgrG_000615900transcript=EgrG_000615900gene=EgrG_000615900
MAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV
```

Comment: Hello Jose, using your command, I get this returned;                                  `sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]`

Comment: use `sed 's/[ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYVBZ]*$/\n&/' file` instead ..... you use `gnu-sed`

Comment: this returns an 'n' where the line break needs to be; `>EgrG_000615900 transcript=EgrG_000615900 gene=EgrG_000615900nMAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV`

Comment: or `sed 's/[ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYVBZ]*$/\'$'\n&/g' file`

Comment: `-r` is GNU-specific, use `-E` instead as it works on GNU and OSX seds (and others?).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/M/\
&/' file
EgrG_000615900transcript=EgrG_000615900gene=EgrG_000615900
MAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV
FIV
```

If that's not all you need then update your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

another `sed`

```
sed -r 's/(^>(.+)transcript=\2gene=\2)/\1\n/' file
```

looking for a pattern `>{KEY}transcript={KEY}gene={KEY}` and inserts newline.

```
>EgrG_000615900transcript=EgrG_000615900gene=EgrG_000615900
MAIRSFGRIAPARSLLIHFKLVTDAFHGEAPSGPYLLPQAARSLLCEKCDGKCVICDSYVRPCTLVRICDECNYGSYQGRCVICGGTGVSDAYYCRESPKPTSFTKGRNMDSKNDLISNKFTMHADVIISILKPGLFVIVDFFIV
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is fixed in length. So just split the line at the column point where you want the new line to start. For example, split the line at the 40th character:

```
sed -E $'s/(^.{40})/\\1\\\n/g' < file
```

(Note: I'm using OS X sed. I've had to escape the pattern with `$''`.)

Answer (score 0):

@DKaplinski: Try:

```
awk --re-interval '{match($0,/.*EgrG_[0-9]{9}MAIRS/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-5);sub(/.*EgrG_[0-9]{9}MAIRS/,"");print "MAIRS" $0}'  Input_file
```

Above will divide EgrG_till 9 digits and MARIS rest of the line with line till EgrG_ and then MARIS with rest of the line. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Re intervals have been enabled by default in GNU awk for several years so get rid of `--re-interval` (or get a new awk!).

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton, yes I have GNU Awk 3.1.7 but some how it is not picking this regex until/unless I put --re-interval. 

Also I have one question(if you wouldn't mind), I was trying to use gsub by putting regex like gsub(/EgrG_[0-9]{9}[^(MAIRS)], but I know it is characters here so how could I use a word here rather than characters, could you please help in same.

Comment: That is a Jurassic version of gawk, more than 5 years out of date, get a modern one! To negate a word/string robustly you have to create a character that doesn't exist in the input, map the word to that character, then negate that character and then convert the character back to the word. e.g. `(gsub(/@/,"@A"); gsub(/X/,"@B"); gsub(/MAIRS/,"X"); gsub(/...[^X]../,...); gsub(/X/,"MAIRS"); gsub(/@B/,"X"); gsub(/@A/,"@")`. Think about it and add print statements to see how that works robustly and post a question if it's not clear.